# постоянная ошибка LNK2019 при сборке любого проекта в microsoft vs 2022

Tags: c++, компиляция, сборка, build-error

Изучая cpp наткнулся на постоянную проблему со сборкой и отладкой файлов в mvs2022. Даже при выводе обычного текста выскакивает ошибка LNK2019

```
#include <iostream>

void Main()
{
   std::cout << "h" << std::endl;
}
```

При сборке выскакивает 2 ошибки :

> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).

> fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

При отладке пишет :

> Не удается запустить программу <путь скомпилированного .exe файла>. Не удается найти указанный файл

Хочу отметить что ошибка выскакивает не сразу, а после написания относительно большого столба кода, какого-то кол-ва редактирований или вставке целого куска кода

Пожалуйста подскажите как решить данную проблему или что я делаю не так

Comment: а почему Main с большой буквы?

Comment: да вопрос только в именовании Main() . спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В c++ функция main должна возвращать код результата выполнения (или код ошибки), поэтому она обязана быть типа `int`.
2. не `Main`, а `main`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "h" << std::endl;
}
```